# JAVA ODBC scroll error despite TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, odbc

I have a JAVA project involving a ODBC database query in which I need to move the cursor in the result set. I've declared the type of `ResultSet` to be `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`, but when I execute the script I get an exception stating the `ResultSet` type is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`. I've pasted my (simplified) project code below, and would appreciate any help.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;  //Necessary package for basic Java utilities
import java.sql.*;                        //Necessary packages for SQL routines

public class test {

  public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) throws Exception {

    // declare variables & create database connection
    System.out.println("Open ODBC Connection....");
    Connection dataConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DSN");
    Statement  stmt           = dataConnection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);      
    int        i              = 0;
    int        N              = 0;

    //loading JDBC-ODBC Bridge driver into memory
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

    // create SQL query string
    String sql = "SELECT ObjRef, IDX, DateListDateAsString FROM ARRAY_BAC_CAL_DateList WHERE DEV_ID=10000 AND INSTANCE=1";

    // run the query
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    // determine number of date entries
    rs.last();
    N = rs.getInt("IDX");

    // close connection
    rs.close();
    dataConnection.close();
    System.out.println ("Connection closed\n");    


  }
}
```

The error I receive is:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Result set type is
>   TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY   at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.last(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:2290)   at
>   test.main(test.java:26)

Line 26 is where I try to move the result set cursor.

Again, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE
```

to:

```
ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if result type has been downgraded from driver using `ResultSet.getWarnings()`: iterate over all [`SQLWarning`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLWarning.html) to check if some settings has been changed by *JDBC-ODBC Bridge driver*.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your above comments I would suggest you either of two ways:

- SQL (Short way): Modify your select query and order it by `desc`, in java code get the first record, thats it !

  ### OR
- Java (Long way):

  1. Fire query to get number of results in the table and get the count value in the java variable OR you may get the row count from `ResultSetMetaData`.
  2. Second, as now you have the row count, traverse in the `ResultSet` row by row and get row at count location(your desired row).

Comment: Yeah, there are other ways to access the last entry and count the total number of entries, which I'm trying to do, but it seems that I should be able to move the resultSet cursor explicitly after declaring "ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE".

Thanks for your input.